# I can't create a second window using tkinter, on os x

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, tkinter

When creating a second window using python 3.6 and tkinter, it is not responsible. I`m using os x 10.11.6. 
In other systems such as Ubuntu, this code works.

```
from tkinter import *

class win2:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.mainloop()

class win1:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()

        self.button = Button(self.root)
        self.button.bind('<Button-1>', self.buttonFunc)
        self.button.pack()

        self.root.mainloop()

    def buttonFunc(self, event):
        windows2 = win2()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    window1 = win1()
```

Comment: I think you are approaching the problem wrong. Your tkinter GUI should only have 1 mainloop. Your `win2` class isn't doing anything. I suggest finding a simple tkinter example and working from there. Also, PyQt is another option for GUIs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a very bad idea to use `Tk()` more than once in your program. Use it to make the root window, and then use `Toplevel()` to make any additional windows.

```
def buttonFunc(self, event):
    Toplevel(self.root)
```

That said, it still looks like you are trying to do something the hard way. Can you describe better what your end goal is?

To make a modal window (a popup) use code like this:

```
try: #python3 imports
    import tkinter as tk
except ImportError: #python3 failed, try python2 imports
    import Tkinter as tk

class Main(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)

        lbl = tk.Label(self, text="this is the main frame")
        lbl.pack()

        btn = tk.Button(self, text='click me', command=self.open_popup)
        btn.pack()

    def open_popup(self):
        print("runs before the popup")
        Popup(self)
        print("runs after the popup closes")

class Popup(tk.Toplevel):
    """modal window requires a master"""
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)

        lbl = tk.Label(self, text="this is the popup")
        lbl.pack()

        btn = tk.Button(self, text="OK", command=self.destroy)
        btn.pack()

        # The following commands keep the popup on top.
        # Remove these if you want a program with 2 responding windows.
        # These commands must be at the end of __init__
        self.transient(master) # set to be on top of the main window
        self.grab_set() # hijack all commands from the master (clicks on the main window are ignored)
        master.wait_window(self) # pause anything on the main window until this one closes

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    window = Main(root)
    window.pack()
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I want to create settings window for my app. Here is the link to my full code https://codeshare.io/GqANWx

Comment: That's a 'modal window'. I edited my answer to show you how to do that. I suggest you also follow my lead in subclassing rather than making attributes like `self.root`.

Comment: @МихайлоПилипишин please don't ask people to do everything for you and give them your full code. This isn't what SO is for...

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me.

```
from tkinter import *

class win1:

    def __init__(self):
        root = Tk()
        button = Button(root)
        button.bind('<Button-1>', self.buttonFunc)
        button.pack()
        root.mainloop()

    def buttonFunc(self, event):
        window2 = win2()

class win2(win1):

    def __init__(self):
        top = Toplevel()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    window1 = win1()
```